# Why is the past tense used here instead of the present tense?

Tags: tenses

Why is the past tense used here instead of the present tense?

> It should make one focused.

Why can you use this sentence? I thought word *make* can only be used with the present tense like this:

> It should make one focus.

Can you please explain?

Answer (score 3):

You’ve misunderstood the analysis of both: those are not past tense and present tense at all — neither of them.

---

## Past Participle

This one:

> It should make one focused.

Is not a verb but a past participle serving as an adjective, as in:

> It should make one drunk.

So *focused* and *drunk* are past participles, not past tenses.

---

## Infinitive

And this one:

> It should make one focus.

Is not a present tense finite verb but rather an infinitive, as in

> It should make one be quiet.

So *focus* and *be* are infinitives, not present tense.